# input/output error when launching any program

Tags: filesystem, backup, fsck

Every program I launch on Ubuntu 16.04 generates an input/output error:

```
$ top
bash: /usr/bin/top: Input/output error
$ pkill firefox
bash: /usr/bin/firefox: Input/output error
$ okular
bash: /usr/bin/okular: Input/output error
```

What is happening and can it be fixed without a reboot?
How to make a backup when the filesystem is damaged?

Comment: Input/output error probably means that your filesystem is damaged and/or your disk is broken. I don't think that you can avoid a reboot to run fsck from a Live USB., Also try to make a backup before rebooting, in case the system fails to come up again.

Comment: @SorenA, how to make a backup when the filesystem is damaged?

Comment: You should have made regular backups *before* you had a problem. Shut down your system, boot from a Live USB, and run a SMART test (look it up) on your hardware. If your hardware is broken, then it's not an Ubuntu problem -- look up paid recovery services in your area. If your hardware is working, then run fsck (look it up) to repair the damaged filesystem. Only after your filesystem is repaired should you try to boot from it...and start making regular backups.